# Is it the package org.papervision3d.core.io what I need to export to .dae?

Tags: actionscript-3, export, papervision3d, collada

I need to create a .DAE file from one DisplayObject3D and do not know how to do it. Only I find information about how importing a DAE. Never of how exporting it.

Thanks.

---

I cannot change simply "mesh" for "container".

I do not understand this line very well:

```
mesh = scene.addChild(new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3));
```

If I do this:

```
mesh = container.addChild(new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3));
```

Then it creates a dae with the paperplane but only the paperplane and not other objects that exist in "container".

How can I create the dae with the objects of my DisplayObject3D "container"?

Thanks

Comment: Its been years since I played with this, but if I remember correctly DAE files are just xml files containing 3D data. A DAE file would be created with a 3D rendering program.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a .DAE file using [ExportCollada](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/core/io/exporters/ExportCollada.html)'s [export()](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/core/io/exporters/ExportCollada.html#export%28%29) static method:

```
trace(ExportCollada.export(yourDisplayObject3D));
```

I've put together a very basic example [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/e9LI):

[image: PV3D DAE Export]

Run the test and double click the stage to save the plane as a .dae file to disk.

**Update**

Nesting objects also work as you can see [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/vqvR):

[image: PV3D DAE Export multiple nested objects]

You mentioned this line:

```
mesh = scene.addChild(new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3));
```

That is just a lazy way to doing multiple things in one line:

1. create a new PaperPlane object
2. add it to the scene
3. assign the PaperPlane object to the mesh variable

It probably makes more sense like this:

```
var mesh:DisplayObject3D = new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3);
scene.addChild(mesh);
```

Your modified snippet:

```
mesh = container.addChild(new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3));
```

says that mesh is equal to the DisplayObject3D returned by adding the paper plane to container, which is the paper plane, so if you're exporting mesh, you only export the plane.
If you export container, you should get the dae with all the child elements that container has.

Might be easier to change this line:

```
data.writeUTFBytes(ExportCollada.export(mesh));
```

to this:

```
data.writeUTFBytes(ExportCollada.export(container));//assuming container is visible here
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. It is just what that needed. I go a lot of time looking for this.

The problem now is that I do not manage to implement it. My DisplayObject3D does not recognize.

 I will continue trying it. Thank you

 Good-bye

Comment: "The problem now is that I do not manage to implement it." ? What do you mean by that ? Have you imported the class ? `import org.papervision3d.core.io.exporters.ExportCollada` ?

Comment: I cannot change simply "mesh" for "container".

Comment: yes you can and should do that when you export "container" as DAE

Comment: Hello again. Pardon for the lateness.
Still I could not have solved it.

If I try this:

trace(container);

Then I obtain this:

4: x:0 y:0 z:0

If I try this:

trace(ExportCollada.export(contenedor_x));

Then I obtain this message of error:

error 1009: cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

I believe that I am going to desist from doing it :(
thank you @GeorgeProfenza

Comment: What happens if you do this: `trace(contenedor_x);` ? I'm not familiar with your setup, but contenedor_x might be initialized yet (a variable is created, but nothing is assigned to it, it's pointing to a null object). Could you share a bit more information about your setup to work out what's wrong ?